# Is there any evidence that any other species are "pre-intelligence"?

Tags: evolution, intelligence

Is there any evidence regarding whether other species might, given time, evolve intelligence as humans have?

I realize "intelligence" is a vague word here, but I'm interested in throwing a wide net, since I imagine the small sample size of positive cases makes finding any evidence at all extremely difficult.

The only information I've been able to find so far seems vague and unscientific, but I'm expecting that is the best I'm going to be able to find.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Unfortunately, the use of the term intelligence really needs better definition. Many species are already much more intelligent than humans in several respects (such as memory for example).

Comment: [Wiki > Animal Cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_cognition) is a long article but it may help you to focus your question and your interest.

Comment: @Remi.b Totally fair, and thanks for the link!

Comment: I found another article on here after I posted this question that is at least tangentially related to this subject, in case any one is interested: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/339/is-there-evidence-that-some-non-human-species-perform-sexual-selection-based-pri

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know, what the intelligence is, but i've got an idea what it can be. 
I've read about smth similar before. I suppose, we can measure intelligence with [working memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_memory) (don't mix with shott-term-mempory)  term (like registers of processor).
There were many experiments that was provided to check how big a working memory of humans and apes.

According to information people got from these experimence, average WM of humans equal to 7, apes - equal to 4 (count of terms subject can manipulate without any significant mistakes). So, apes can be considered as pre-intelligence this way. But anyway it is still controversial question.

You can also google articles like this:  http://www.pnas.org/content/110/Supplement_2/10371.full.pdf

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all well

Comment: Right, but i've just tried to make "intelligence" term more suitable for measuring and tried to think of what we can get from it. Actually, if we think of all apes, several of these (like gorrilas) are considered like in a "deadlock of brain evolution". Sometimes we can find some of chimpanzee for ex. or even gorrilas that shows outstanding brainworks and ability to learn something complex (bonobo Kanzi for example). But we should keep in mind, that such individuals are not general and we can't say it has intelligence as species.